# How do I know which version of forge I should download for my Minecraft mods?

Tags: minecraft-mods, minecraft-forge, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to get different mods for Minecraft on my computer. 
I have followed a few different instructions I've found online With no luck.
It all says to download the right Version of forge. Stupid question I know, but how do I know which one is right? What I am doing obviously isn't working.

Can someone really break it down to me as I'm new to this and trying to get these different mods for my son.

Please explain as detailed as possible please!

We have Minecraft Windows 10

Comment: Hi, It looks like you've got some conflicting answers due to the information you provided. If you got minecraft from the Microsoft Store, you have the Bedrock Version. If you downloaded Minecraft from the Mojang Website, then you have the Java Version. I strongly suggest an edit to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft forge only works with the java version of minecraft, not the windows 10 version of minecraft.  Unfortunately, if you want to use mods, you'll have to get the java edition.

[Here's a link](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1274139-different-minecraft-editions) that explains all the different versions.  Again, only the top one (Java Edition) will work with minecraft forge mods.

Comment: Minecraft Windows 10 isn't the normal minecraft? I'm sorry. I think since the version 1.10 I haven't played so I am a bit outdated. Mod doesn't work there?

Comment: The OP isn't clear on which version. Mods work in 1.10 of the JAVA version. Bedrock Version isn't moddable in the same way, but can use 'Behavior Packs'.

Answer (score 0):

Since a while I don't play minecraft but I am sure it is still the same method.

Each mod has its own requisite of the minecraft forge version, but usually all the mods use the same (so I isn't a big problem). Usually (I would say the 99% of times) a newer version of the forge will support mods with a lower requisite. When you download a mod you should do it on pages where it's displayed the Minecraft Forge version requisite like (I think) [curseforge](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods) or another page.

If you are using a mod which need a newer version of the Minecraft Forge and you load the game it will display a screen that will say which mods aren't compatible and which minimal Forge version you will need.

Instead, if you open your minecraft and get a crash report it will be more difficult to find the propper version. I recommend download the "recommended" version on https://files.minecraftforge.net/ and if that doesn't work you should try the "lastest" version.

**Remember, if you aren't sure which is the right version** the 90% of times it will be the "**recommended**" version of https://files.minecraftforge.net/, the 8% of times the "**lastest**" and the other 2% will be bad luck :(.

Maybe, if you post your minecraft version and which mods you are trying to install I could try it.

Comment: Same thing goes with GTA and rage hook. Many mods require version x or higher as at version X was probably when the code was added which the mod uses. later version will also most likely have that same code

Comment: @Alphex, I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean with "GTA and rage hook", but apart of that I think I said the same as you but with different words, right?

Comment: Yes basically the same

Answer (score 0):

You can't use mods on the Bedrock version (Windows 10, Xbox One, Nintendo Switch, Android, iOS) of Minecraft. Mods are only available in the Java version (Windows, Mac OS, Linux) due to the modable nature of the game. There is an alternative on Bedrock thought, they are called Behaviour Packs. Check out this tutorial:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Only Mods work on Java Edition. To get mods for Minecraft Windows 10, you use add on's instead, which are far different from Mods.

You can get mods on minecraft bedrock though (the type of minecraft that Minecraft Windows 10 is classified), but it's only for Android and you need a special program.

So if you are getting mods for your son, then either get Minecraft Java Edition or Add-On's.